# Jersey Test Framework

Tags: jersey

I have a non maven project.  I would like to test my jersey rest services using the Jersey Test Framework.  The jersey docs only relate to maven for the jersey test framework.  Is it possible to add a jar or library to the project to use this framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Jersey client](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/chapter_deps.html#core_client) instead of Jersey Test Framework have two advantages:

1. It's well documented and only needs [the jersey-client JAR](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/chapter_deps.html#core_client)
2. The written code is standard and can be use by the Java clients of your services

Comment: can you supply some examples of documentation

Comment: Thank, you.  Can you explain what this tests.  As it seems that a lot of objects are mocked out.

Comment: There ain't any mock in this sample. It starts a jetty server (`@Rule`) and ask URI for answers. Then it get the response in a typed object. The resource [is discribed here](http://bit.ly/u4tVVu). The test is made of two steps 1. create products via POST (`@Before`) 2. verify there are effectivly created  with GET

Comment: Good for integration tests, but they're not really unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to add Maven to your project for some reasons

1. ability to use and helpful dependencies
2. having mechanism to create a build of you application with one command like `mvn clean package`

If you use Ant scripts you can easily call old Ant scripts from Maven with [Apache Maven AntRun Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin) without significant Ant scripts rebuilding.